# Isotopy between two open disks on a surface

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

So I have a (compact) surface $\Sigma$ and two open disks on the surface call them $A$ and $A'$ such that the intersection contains a simple curve $P$. What I want to do is construct an isotopy between $A$ and $A'$ which leaves $P$ fixed.

I'll let you know what I have so far, but maybe there is a cleaner way to do this.
In the intersection there is an open set, U, around $P$ which is homeomorphic to the disk, (simply take an $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of $P$). I want to stretch $U - P$ via some isotopy $F$ to the remainder of $A$ and then another one $G$ which takes $U-P$ to the remainder of $A'$. I'm pretty sure that would be enough but I'm not sure how to work that bit of detail out though.

Once we have those two I can compose those two isotopies (well one with it's inverse) to get what I want.

Any hints to my missing part?

Edit: Corrected an error.

Comment: You're definitely on the right track. Not sure if this is the kind of hint you are looking for, but I would consider also a $U'$ that is a $2\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $P$. Then, you can find an isotopy that does nothing on $U$ and sends the annulus $A \setminus U$ to $U' \setminus U$.

Comment: I was considering that, but then when you compose our isotopies you run into a problem. $U$ sitting inside of $A$ is a different embedding of the disk into $\Sigma$ than $U$ sitting inside of $A'$. So then you'd need another isotopy sending $U$ to itself which isotoped the two different embeddings to each other. I'd like to avoid this problem.